# Test if some field has been initialized in python

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to write a test in Python that checks if a method in a class that I am writing sets the attribute value for a dataset in some Hdf file. The logic is the following: An instance of the class is constructed by passing an instance of *h5py.File*, then one method creates a dataset inside this file. In the next step I have another method that sets certain attributes for this dataset.

What I am trying to test is if my class method *create_attributes(self,attributes)* sets the field *hdf_file[dset_name].attrs[attr_name]* to some value that is passed in the variable *attributes*. However, I would like to avoid to actually create a Hdf file. So far I have tried to mock an instance of a hdf file and work with that. The minimal working code example would be the following:

```
import h5py

class TestSomething:
    @mock.patch('h5py.File')
    def test_if_attr_is_initialized(self,mock_hdf):
        # Here I would like to call a function that basically executes
        # the following line:
        mock_hdf['test_dset'].attrs['test_field']='value'

        # Then I want to check if the attribute field has been assigned
        assert mock_hdf['test_dset'].attrs['test_field']=='value'
```

Can anybody help me finding the correct thing to do to check whether or not the attribute in the hdf file is set correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am a complete newbie to all the mocking techniques.

Edit:

In the following I am providing a minimal code example for both the class, and the respective test as requeseted by wwii:

```
import h5py

class HdfWriter():
     def __init__(self,hdf_file):
         self.hdf_file=hdf_file

     def create_attrs(self,attributes):
         dset_name=attributes.keys()[0]
         attrs=attributes[dset_name]

         for key in attrs:
             self.hdf_file[dset_name].attrs[key]=attrs[key]
```

Please note here that with a real hdf file I would first have to create a dataset but I would like to leave that for another test. The following test should just check, whether for a hypothetical hdf file, which has the dataset *test_dset* the attributes for this data set are written:

```
import h5py
import HdfWriter

class TestSomething:
    @mock.patch('h5py.File')
    def test_if_attr_is_initialized(self,mock_hdf):
        writer=hw.HdfWriter(mock_hdf)
        attr={'test_dset':{'test_field':'test_value'}}
        writer.create_attrs(attr)

        assert writer.hdf_file['test_dset'].attrs['test_field']=='value'
```

Comment: You might not have posted enough information.  Seems like you want to be mocking/patching the unbound class methods and/or attributes.  Can you post a minimal example of the class?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... I have now posted a minimal example for both the class and the respective test. The class as I posted it does not work, it would need another method for creating datasets. For testing I want to avoid involving the function for creating datasets.

Comment: Are you asking how to mock an ```h5py.File``` so that it has a dataset item with an attrs attribute? Or are you asking for the best way to test ```create_attrs```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking `h5py.File`

```
class HdfWriter():
     def __init__(self,hdf_file):
         self.hdf_file=hdf_file

     def create_attrs(self,attributes):
         dset_name=attributes.keys()[0]
         attrs=attributes[dset_name]

         for key in attrs:
             self.hdf_file[dset_name].attrs[key]=attrs[key]
```

For the purpose of the `create_attrs` method, `hdf_file` behaves as a dictionary that returns an object that also behaves like a dictionary. The docs explain pretty clearly how to mock a dictionary.

You need a mock that has an `attrs` attribute that behaves like a dictionary:

```
import mock

attrs_d = {}
def setattrs(name, value):
##    print 'setattrs', name, value
    attrs_d[name] = value
def getattrs(name):
##    print 'getattrs', name
    return attrs_d[name]
mock = mock.MagicMock()
mock.attrs.__setitem__.side_effect = setattrs
mock.attrs.__getitem__.side_effect = getattrs
```

You need a mock for `hdf_file` that behaves like a dictionary and will return the mock object created above.

```
hdf_d = {'test_dset':mock}
def getitem(name):
##    print 'getitem', name
    return hdf_d[name]
def setitem(name, value):
    hdf_d[name] = value
mock_hdf = mock.MagicMock()
mock_hdf.__getitem__.side_effect = getitem
mock_hdf.__setitem__.side_effect = setitem
```

`hdf_d`, as implemented, only works for the key `'test_dset'`. Depending on your needs it may be better for `getitems` to just return `mock` regardless of the name argument.

```
def test_if_attr_is_initialized(mock_hdf):
    writer=HdfWriter(mock_hdf)
    attr={'test_dset':{'test_field':'test_value'}}
    writer.create_attrs(attr)
    print writer.hdf_file['test_dset'].attrs['test_field'], '==', attr['test_dset']['test_field']

    assert writer.hdf_file['test_dset'].attrs['test_field']=='test_value'

test_if_attr_is_initialized(mock_hdf)

>>> 
test_value == test_value
>>>
```

This should suffice to test `create_attrs` but it may not be optimal - maybe someone will chime in with some refinements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to work this out... I really appreciate this. I am just starting to learn the mocking techniques.